# Bluetooth dongle detected but not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, compatibility, ubuntu-22.04, dongle

I've installed ubuntu 22.04 and at some point my bluetooth stopped working.

I have a bluetooth external dongle: Amitosai MTS-BT5PRO (I think the problem might be with this device, but its strange that in ubuntu 20 it worked fine)

The service is up and running (in theory) but it cannot detect new devices nor connect to the ones already paired.

Prove that the device is detected (Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio):

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0107 TP-Link TL-WN821N v5/v6 [RTL8192EU]
Bus 001 Device 044: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 043: ID 1b3f:1167 Generalplus Technology Inc. WEB CAM
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 258a:002a SINO WEALTH Gaming KB 
Bus 001 Device 041: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The service seems running (as shown in the imaged [bluetooth service running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKhGV.png))

But the logs throw two errors:

```
jul 26 10:44:40 andy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Starting SDP server
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
jul 26 10:44:40 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
jul 26 10:45:14 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (0x05)
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
jul 26 10:47:11 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.125 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
jul 26 10:47:19 andy bluetoothd[9468]: Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
```

The errors are:

1. Failed to set mode: Not Supported (0x0c)
2. Failed to set mode: Authentication Failed (0x05)

When I restart the service, a bluetooth error shows up:

[Ubuntu error when restarted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEzNO.png)

And `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` throws this:

```
~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[sudo] password for andresjalife: 
[    4.829449] usb 1-5: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    6.954047] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.954086] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    6.954087] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.954090] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.954091] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.954094] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.989904] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    6.990827] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    6.990830] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[    6.991442] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[    6.991717] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
[    7.160832] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
[    7.796472] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.796476] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.796479] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    9.000301] Bluetooth: hci1: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
[   21.885974] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.885981] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.885984] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.908309] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c24 failed: -110
[   23.908309] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   25.924303] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   25.924328] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c24 failed: -110
[   27.940333] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[   27.940334] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c24 failed: -110
[ 4133.077329] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 401 failed: -110
[ 4133.077376] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 4135.093401] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c3a failed: -110
[ 4135.093405] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c3a tx timeout
[ 4135.093413] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 4137.109361] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0401 tx timeout
[ 4137.109366] Bluetooth: hci0: No gpio to reset Realtek device, ignoring
[ 4137.109392] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 401 failed: -110
[ 4259.943761] usb 1-12: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[ 4259.949371] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[ 4259.950343] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[ 4259.950357] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[ 4259.950518] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[ 4259.950618] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
[ 4260.099367] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
[ 4271.990867] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x 402 failed: -110
[ 4271.990906] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0402 tx timeout
```

Do you know what could be the error?

If you think it's the dongle itself, would you recommend me one that's compatible with ubuntu 22.04?

I've tried many solutions posted here, but none of them worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since this is not a question about programming it is off-topic here. Please take the [tour] for information about what to post here. Your question is a great fit for the [Ubuntu StackExchange](http://askubuntu.com) though, feel free to ask it there :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Bluetooth option is enabled in your laptop’s BIOS/UEFI settings. These settings control the hardware of your laptop, and if Bluetooth is disabled here, it will not be detected by any operating system you are running.

To access the BIOS/UEFI settings, restart your laptop and press the appropriate key (usually F2, F12, DEL, or ESC) during the initial boot process. Once in the BIOS/UEFI settings, look for an option related to Bluetooth and ensure it is enabled. Save any changes and restart your system.